# Debugging F# in Xamarin Studio 4.0.3 throws an error

Tags: f#, monodevelop, xamarin, xamarin-studio

I have installed Xamarin Studio 4.0.1 on Windows 8 x64 from http://monodevelop.com/Download . When I ran Xamarin, it got updated to 4.0.3. I have installed F# bindings. I have created new F# console project. When I run it, it works fine. When I set a break-point and run it, I get the following error. Any idea, why that happens?

> System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x80070032): The request is not supported. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070032)
>      at Microsoft.Samples.Debugging.CorDebug.NativeApi.ICorDebug.CreateProcess(String lpApplicationName, String lpCommandLine, SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES lpProcessAttributes, SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES lpThreadAttributes, Int32 bInheritHandles, UInt32 dwCreationFlags, IntPtr lpEnvironment, String lpCurrentDirectory, STARTUPINFO lpStartupInfo, PROCESS_INFORMATION lpProcessInformation, CorDebugCreateProcessFlags debuggingFlags, ICorDebugProcess& ppProcess)
>      at Microsoft.Samples.Debugging.CorDebug.CorDebugger.CreateProcess(String applicationName, String commandLine, SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES processAttributes, SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES threadAttributes, Boolean inheritHandles, Int32 creationFlags, IntPtr environment, String currentDirectory, STARTUPINFO startupInfo, PROCESS_INFORMATION& processInformation, CorDebugCreateProcessFlags debuggingFlags)
>      at Microsoft.Samples.Debugging.CorDebug.CorDebugger.CreateProcess(String applicationName, String commandLine, String currentDirectory, IDictionary`2 environment, Int32 flags)
>      at MonoDevelop.Debugger.Win32.CorDebuggerSession.OnRun(DebuggerStartInfo startInfo)
>      at Mono.Debugging.Client.DebuggerSession.<>c__DisplayClassc.b__a()

Comment: Looking at the stack, it will be hard to say by anyone except the developers of Xamarin. Since you own Win8, have you tried the same from within VisualStudio? There is a slight possibility that your F# runtime is faulty and that it will crash there too, but thats.. rather unlikely. I'd try filing a bug at Xamarin's, especially if it wa OK at 4.0.1

Comment: Visual Studio 2012 works fine. I will file a bug. Thanks.

Comment: debugger support for F# in Xamarin Studio does work on Mac, I think this maybe an issue with the Windows version

Comment: Exact same error occurs when debugging a web application and apparently it is caused by the .NET debugger. Rebuilding against Mono and using their debugger should solve it, however I haven' t figured out how yet (source: http://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/1491/xamarin-studio-and-debugging-asp-net-mvc-yields-0x80070032).

Comment: Is this still an issue?

Comment: @mydogisbox: To be honest, I was not able to make debugging F# work under Xamarin Studio and I gave up. With Microsoft .NET debugger, Xamarin Studio crashes and with Mono Soft Debugger, any breakpoint set in F# tutorial project is never hit.

Comment: The .NET debugger is quite low priority for Xamarin as their main platform is Mono, there is a bug logged on bugzilla for this:  https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=3537

Answer (score 1):

The problem with the Win32 Debugger is that we do not support x64 debugging. Try debugging the Application in 32bit and it will work.

We need to implement remote debuggin, aka spawning a 64bit debugger so we can debug a 64bit app. We use MDbg as a backend.

Also check:
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jmstall/archive/2006/03/08/debugging-cross-platform.aspx