# Debugger operation failed The request is not supported. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070032)

Tags: c#, debugging, xamarin-studio

I have a C# project that was initially created by VS2013. I open it in Xamarin and it builds fine, the executable file is created and can be started from outside Xamarin.

But if I try to start it with Run->Start Debugging, it shows this error:

```
Debugger operation failed
The request is not supported. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070032)
```

[image]

The only similar question I found was for F# - [Debugging F# in Xamarin Studio 4.0.3 throws an error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16215690/debugging-f-in-xamarin-studio-4-0-3-throws-an-error), and they suggest it is because the project is 64-bit, but I'm not sure if this applies to C# as well.

How can I fix this error?

Comment: There is two known cases when it could happen. One is when you debug x64 process and second if you debug ASP.NET

Comment: Any error starting with 0x8 indicates an invalid pointer.  You may of have a null object or pointer to a memory location outside the scope of you application.  For debugging to work you need a symbol table (map) that contains debugging info.  So I suspect you do not have the symbols which is returning a null.

Comment: @jdweng No. Any error that starts with the top bit set is an error. If the top bit is not set it isn't an error. See: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms690088%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: Read the article again.  An 8 is a windows error.  It is really an exception that comes from the microporcessor.  In this case the solution was to us x86 processor since the CPU in the computer couldn't run x64 compiled code.

Comment: "One is when you debug x64 process". I am getting the same problem with a straightforward C++ project in VS2012. Is there some reason why VS doesn't support debugging 64-bit programs - surely not!!!.

Answer (score 1):

If you arrive here as a result of trying to debug a unit test in Xamarin (in my case on a Mac) and you see the Debugger Operation Failed message, it may be because in the drop-down for your chosen build (on the header bar area) you still have release selected. I switched that to debug, and then the option in the unit tests to 'debug test' worked.

Answer (score 0):

It really did turn out to be [because of the architecture](https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=753). But in my case the architecture was AnyCPU, not x64, and it couldn't be changed from inside Xamarin:

[image]

So instead I opened the .csproj file in Notepad++ and used Replace All to replace all mentions of "AnyCPU" to "x86". After reloading the solution in Xamarin, the debugger now works.

Answer (score 0):

I got this same error while adding a binding in IIS Manager. It also prevented Windows Update to check updates. The issue was the cipher suite list.

If you come across the same issue, here is the solution:

1. Go to "**Start > Run**". Enter: **gpedit.msc**
2. In the left pane, expand “**Computer Configuration > Administrative Templates > Network > SSL Configuration Settings**”
   In the right pane, right click “**SSL Cipher Suite Order**” and choose “**Edit**”
3. Save the text inside “**SSL Chiper Suite**” field to a Notepad for backup
4. Select “**Not Configured**”
5. Click “**OK**”
6. Restart the server (gpupdate doesn’t enforce this setting. You should restart the server)

Source: [The request is not supported (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070032)](https://port135.com/2020/08/06/the-request-is-not-supported-exception-from-hresult-0x80070032/)